# Primefaces 11 with Java 8 and Payara-micro does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, payara, payara-micro

I and my colleagues are porting an old application based on JSF 2.2 + Tomcat 9 on Jakarta EE 9 2 + OpenJDK 1.8 + JSF 3.0 + Payara 5.2022.2 as it fulfils Jakarta EE 9 specification.

We changed imports, web.xml, pom.xml and after a few iterations we get to compile the project. But using payara-micro:start to deploy and run the application we have a problem apparently with primefaces 11.0.0.

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.8.0_332
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5716)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1871)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1623)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:361)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:623)
        at fish.payara.deployment.admin.InitializeAllApplicationsCommand.execute(InitializeAllApplicationsCommand.java:75)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:183)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.run(CommandExecutorImpl.java:96)
        at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.bootStrap(PayaraMicroImpl.java:1060)
        at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.create(PayaraMicroImpl.java:231)
        at fish.payara.micro.impl.PayaraMicroImpl.main(PayaraMicroImpl.java:218)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:50)
        at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:114)
        at fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:73)
        at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.create(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:88)
        at fish.payara.micro.boot.PayaraMicroLauncher.main(PayaraMicroLauncher.java:72)
        at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:456)
```

Here's the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.caditech</groupId>
  <artifactId>mdmweb-nuovo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <payaraVersion>5.2022.2</payaraVersion>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
            <version>5.2022.2</version>
          </artifactItem>
          <deployWar>true</deployWar>
          <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.0</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>it.caditech</groupId>
  <artifactId>mdmweb-nuovo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <!-- <finalName>mdmweb-nuovissimo</finalName> -->
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>fish.payara.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-micro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <payaraVersion>5.2022.2</payaraVersion>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
            <version>5.2022.2</version>
          </artifactItem>
          <deployWar>true</deployWar>
          <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <tomeeVersion>1.7.1</tomeeVersion>
          <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>it.caditech</groupId>
      <artifactId>mdm</artifactId>
      <version>6.43.14</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>it.caditech</groupId>
      <artifactId>mdm</artifactId>
      <version>6.43.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.0</version>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c.css/sac -->
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
      <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

[EDITED]

I found out that the class that raises the problem is in web-fragment.xml inside the primefaces.jar in the `listener` tag. I tried to comment it, but this new error raises

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1821)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1484)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Hmmm that is strange. It looks like a class compatibility issue but PF is compiled for Java 8 so it should not be reporting that.

Comment: @Melloware I found out that the class that raises the problem is in web-fragment.xml inside the primefaces.jar in the `<listener>` tag

Comment: Yep it is this class `org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener` but all of PF is compiled for Java8 so how could it be getting `unsupported major or minor version numbers` when you are using Java 8 to run.  UNless its an issue with Your JDK8?

Answer (score 2):

When I run `javap -v` on `org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener` class in PrimeFaces 11 its showing Bytecode version `52` which is JDK8.

```
C:\Temp>javap -v UploadedFileCleanerListener.class
Classfile /C:/Temp/UploadedFileCleanerListener.class
  Last modified Dec 9, 2021; size 1419 bytes
  MD5 checksum b8584b71366ba6daea3f09087d7ce098
  Compiled from "UploadedFileCleanerListener.java"
public class org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener implements jakarta.servlet.ServletRequestListener
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
```

See: https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/

```
JDK Version Bytecode Version
Java 5  49.0
Java 6  50.0
Java 7  51.0
Java 8  52.0
Java 9  53.0
Java 10 54.0
Java 11 55.0
Java 12 56.0
Java 13 57.0
Java 14 58.0
Java 15 59.0
Java 16 60.0
Java 17 61.0
Java 18 62.0
Java 19 63.0
Java 20 64.0
```

Comment: Yes I understand, in fact I can't explain the error. I'm using Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK 1.8.0_332.

This is the detailed message: 
`java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.8.0_332`

Comment: Could be a bug in Temurin?  I have you tried downgrading your version from _332 to an older version?

Comment: It could be. I tried with Temurin 1.8.0_312b07 and 1.8.0_307b08, but I have the same problem

Comment: Tried also with Amazon Corretto 1.8.0_342. Same thing
`java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class org.primefaces.webapp.UploadedFileCleanerListener has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.8.0_342`